# how to configure tornado for pycharm

Tags: python, asynchronous, pycharm, tornado, configure

I install the tornado frame work

now I want to code with tornado but when I run the code in pycharm it doesn't undestand imported code

**Code :**

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello world")


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

What should I do that i could easily run the tornado code in pycharm ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need just to import in this way:

```
import tornado
```

because in your code you use

```
tornado.web.RequestHandler()
tornado.web.Application()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
```

or if you want you can use `from` statment

```
from tornado import web, ioloop

# and now you can write in this way
web.RequestHandler()
web.Application()
ioloop.IOLoop.current()
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
import tornado.options
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.options import options

from settings import settings
from handlers import URLS
from handlers.error import BaseErrorHandler


tornado.options.parse_command_line()


def main():

    settings.TORNADO['default_handler_class'] = BaseErrorHandler
    app = tornado.web.Application(URLS, **settings.TORNADO)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, xheaders=True)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because of Pycharm's python environment. If you want to solve this problem, you should

1. Open your pycharm
2. click “File” which in menu
3. click Setting
4. click Project:(your project Name) -> project interpreter
5. and you can see the python Version you are using in the project .then click the + which is green. and install TORNADO in pycharm.then it can work